# PowerShell ExpandProperty

Tags: powershell, syntax

I am trying to run a PowerShell command that will save the Exchange `MailboxGUID` to a variable.

Normally, I would use the `ExpandProperty` switch to achieve this goal. However, this is not working for me.

Here is is the command (and the resulting output) without the switch:

```
Get-MailboxLocation –user email@domain.com | Where-Object { $_.MailboxLocationType -eq 'Primary' } | Select MailboxGuid

MailboxGuid                         
-----------                         
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
```

When I add the `ExpandProperty` switch, I'm not getting the MailboxGuid value.

Instead, I'm getting the following output:

```
 Get-MailboxLocation –user $User | Where-Object { $_.MailboxLocationType -eq 'Primary' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MailboxGuid

Guid                                
----                                
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's expected, because the `MailboxGuid` contains an object of the type `System.Guid`. I assume you just want to get the value of it so you can do `(Get-MailboxLocation –user email@domain.com | Where-Object { .... }).MailboxGuid.Guid`